# Is there a way to show related model ids without sideloading or embedding data

Tags: miragejs

My understanding is that using `serializeIds: 'always'` will give me this data, but it does not.

**Here's what I'm expecting:**

```
{
  id="1"
  title="some title"
  customerId="2"
}
```

**Instead the output I'm receiving is:**

```
{
  id="1"
  title="some title"
}
```

**My code looks something like this:**

```
import {
  Server,
  Serializer,
  Model,
  belongsTo,
  hasMany,
  Factory
} from "miragejs";
import faker from "faker";

const ApplicationSerializer = Serializer.extend({
  // don't want a root prop
  root: false,
  // true required to have root:false
  embed: true,
  // will always serialize the ids of all relationships for the model or collection in the response
  serializeIds: "always"
});

export function makeServer() {
  let server = newServer({
    models: {
      invoice: Model.extend({
        customer: belongsTo()
      }),
      customer: Model.extend({
        invoices: hasMany()
      })
    },

    factories: {
      invoice: Factory.extend({
        title(i) {
          return `Invoice ${i}`;
        },
        afterCreate(invoice, server) {
          if (!invoice.customer) {
            invoice.update({
              customer: server.create("customer")
            });
          }
        }
      }),
      customer: Factory.extend({
        name() {
          let fullName = () =>
            `${faker.name.firstName()} ${faker.name.lastName()}`;

          return fullName;
        }
      })
    },

    seeds(server) {
      server.createList("invoice", 10);
    },

    serializers: {
      application: ApplicationSerializer,
      invoice: ApplicationSerializer.extend({
        include: ["customer"]
      })
    },

    routes() {
      this.namespace = "api";

      this.get("/auth");
    }
  });
}
```

Changing the config to `root: true, embed: false,` provides the correct output in the `invoice` models, but adds the root and sideloads the customer, which I don't want.

Comment: Looks like you might just have a typo – `const ApplicationsSerializer` you have an extra s!

Comment: Thanks, just a typo when I wrote the post unfortunately. I've updated it. My original code doesn't have that typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've run into some strange behavior with how how `serializeIds` interacts with `embed`.

First, it's confusing why you need to set `embed: true` when you're just trying to disable the root. The reason is because `embed` defaults to false, so if you remove the root and try to include related resources, Mirage doesn't know where to put them. This is a confusing mix of options and Mirage should really have different "modes" that take this into account.

Second, it seems that when `embed` is true, Mirage basically ignores the `serializeIds` option, since it thinks your resources will always be embedded. (The idea here is that a foreign key is used to fetch related resources separately, but when they're embedded they always come over together.) This is also confusing and doesn't need to be the case. I've [opened a tracking issue](https://github.com/miragejs/miragejs/issues/393) in Mirage to help address these points.

As for you today, the best way to solve this is to leave `root` to true and `embed` false, which are both the defaults, so that `serializeIds` works properly, and then just write your own `serialize()` function to remove the key for you:

```
const ApplicationSerializer = Serializer.extend({
  // will always serialize the ids of all relationships for the model or collection in the response
  serializeIds: "always",

  serialize(resource, request) {
    let json = Serializer.prototype.serialize.apply(this, arguments);

    let root = resource.models ? this.keyForCollection(resource.modelName) : this.keyForModel(resource.modelName)

    return json[root];
  }
});
```

You should be able to test this out on both `/invoices` and `/invoices/1`.

[Check out this REPL example](https://miragejs.com/repl/v2/503e7754c0) and try making a request to each URL.

Here's the config from the example:

```
import {
  Server,
  Serializer,
  Model,
  belongsTo,
  hasMany,
  Factory,
} from "miragejs";
import faker from "faker";

const ApplicationSerializer = Serializer.extend({
  // will always serialize the ids of all relationships for the model or collection in the response
  serializeIds: "always",

  serialize(resource, request) {
    let json = Serializer.prototype.serialize.apply(this, arguments);

    let root = resource.models ? this.keyForCollection(resource.modelName) : this.keyForModel(resource.modelName)

    return json[root];
  }
});

export default new Server({
  models: {
    invoice: Model.extend({
      customer: belongsTo(),
    }),
    customer: Model.extend({
      invoices: hasMany(),
    }),
  },

  factories: {
    invoice: Factory.extend({
      title(i) {
        return "Invoice " + i;
      },
      afterCreate(invoice, server) {
        if (!invoice.customer) {
          invoice.update({
            customer: server.create("customer"),
          });
        }
      },
    }),
    customer: Factory.extend({
      name() {
        return faker.name.firstName() + " " + faker.name.lastName();
      },
    }),
  },

  seeds(server) {
    server.createList("invoice", 10);
  },

  serializers: {
    application: ApplicationSerializer,
  },

  routes() {
    this.resource("invoice");
  },
});
```

Hopefully that clears things up + sorry for the confusing APIs!

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. Just happy to have something like Mirage to utilize, great work!

Comment: Just had time to check out the WIP Inspector. Awesome tool.